# Generating link list to pages specified by product database list?

Tags: php, html, mysql

******Update********: I'm almost there, but the id in this code:

```
<?php
while($productData = mysqli_fetch_array($p_query, MYSQL_ASSOC)){
echo '<a href="../product.php?id="'.$productData["id"].'">'.$productData["product_name"].'</a><br         />';
};
?>
```

won't connect with the product.php code for some reason:

```
$id=$_GET['id'];

include_once("php_includes/db_conx.php");

$p_sql = "SELECT * FROM products where id = '$id'";
$p_query = mysqli_query($db_conx, $p_sql);

$prodData = mysqli_fetch_array($p_query, MYSQL_ASSOC);
```

In the address bar it is showing as 'root/product.php?id=' with no product id number.

xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx

got something I dont know how to tackle. It's probably obvious to most but I'm a newbie. Would appreciate the help!

I'm trying to get this php to generate a list of product links rather than plain text products list and these links would go to a page that displays info from database on each product. So 1, how do I produce links instead from the code below? I only mainly know html and css but obviously a href isn't working for me as that is not php.

```
<?php
    while($productData = mysqli_fetch_array($p_query, MYSQL_ASSOC)){
    echo $productData["product_name"]."<br />";
};
?>
```

2, the actual trickier bit is then using info from that product link on the general template product page to pull info from the database on that particular product because I don't know how to take that product_name forward into the new product.php file

Hope I'm being clear!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

guessing you have an id to:

```
 echo <'a href="code.php?id="'.$productData["product_id"].'">'.$productData["product_name"].'</a><br />';
```

code.php:

```
$id=$_GET['id'];
```

you can parse the name if you prefer, but make suer its url friendly or use `url_encode()`

Answer (score 0):

If you have an ID field on the product table, use the product ID in the query string for the product link,

```
<?php
while($productData = mysqli_fetch_array($p_query, MYSQL_ASSOC)){
    echo "<a href=\"/product.php?id={$productData['product_id']}\">
              {$productData['product_name']}
          </a><br />";
}
?>
```

In a file called product.php

```
<?php
    // always turn on errors in development
    mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);

    $p_query = "select * from product where id = ?";
    $stmt = $mysqli->prepare($p_query);
    $stmt->bind_param('i', $_GET['product_id']);
    if ($stmt->execute()) {
        $result = $stmt->get_result();
        $product = $result->fetch_assoc();
        print_r($product);
    }    
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

For that, I use embedding PHP in HTML, like this:

My store has main page, with no $_GET data, and it makes a list of links.
When user goes to the page, it queries the database, and then it has a while loop to echo out all links to the products.

Products information is at store.php?id=*product id*

So, you might be asking how to make that list of links, right?

I close the PHP tags, and then, in HTML, I write:

```
<a href="store.php?id='<?php echo $product_id;?>'"><?php echo $product_id;?></a>
```

And then I open the PHP tags again and proceed with the loop...

This is my first answer on these forums, and I am quite new to all this, because I only have 14 years. Hope you find my answer helpful!

*** Update ***

You can't use ../ syntax in HTML link reference attributes.
If you want to access root, just use / before the path from root to file.